# Simple Next Page Pagnation MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I'm trying to figure out if this will work in some sense. Right now of course it's not. I'm throwing now errors, but I'm also not getting anything outputting with the $nextLink variable..

Here is the full so we're clear how it all comes together:

```
<?php
// Check to see the URL variable is set and that it exists in the database
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
// Connect to the MySQL database
include "includes/db_conx.php";
$id = intval($_GET['id']);// filter everything but numbers
// Use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product
// details, if no then exit this script and give message why


$sql = "UPDATE content SET views=views+1 WHERE ID=$id";
$update = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//


if ($productCount > 0) {
// get all the product details
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$id = $row["id"];
$article_title = $row["article_title"];
$category = $row["category"];
$readmore = $row["readmore"];
$author = $row["author"];
$date_added = $row["date_added"];
$article = $row["article"];
$newDate = substr($date_added, 0, 10); 
}
} else {
echo "That item does not exist.";
exit();
}

} else {
echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
exit();
}
$sqltwo = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id =(select min(id) from content where id > '$id') LIMIT 1";
$next = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqltwo);
if($next > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($next)){
$id = $row["id"];
$nextLink = '$id';
}
}

?>
```

and here is the snippet I'm working through.

```
$sqltwo = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id =(select min(id) from content where id > '$id') LIMIT 1";
$next = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sqltwo);
if($next > 0){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($next)){
$id = $row["id"];
$nextLink = '$id';
}
}
```

I'm trying to select the next row by grabbing the bunch after current id and picking the next one to feed the $nextLink for the the HTML.

This was my vardump for $next

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(10)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: Debugging is your friend. Try `mysqli_error`, `var_dump`, and so on. Post any errors you may be having as well.

Comment: @remyabel I've updated the original post...for reference I'm working from id 10 so the new number should be above that. page id is currently 10

Comment: OH BOY.....it seems in my hunt to debug I forgot to add more test rows to the database...I'm not sure that is something that can be debugged...thanks! I think I got it.

Comment: @Chris also check below ... if you will try to print `$nextLink` you wont get the desired output due to reasons given below. Hope it helps solve it :)

Comment: @woofmeow that is something I noticed before when I started debugging, but I appreciate the heads up. I'll give it to ya though because I can't accept the other as it is not an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you . Glad to be of help @Chris :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not getting the desired output for the `$nextLink` variable is because you have enclosed it in single quotes `'` .

Variables inside double quotes `"` get evaluated by the parser.  Variables inside double quotes `'` do not get evaluated by the parser and are treated as literal strings.

Instead of this

`$nextLink = '$id';`

Use this

`$nextLink = $id;` or even this will do (but is not advised ) `$nextLink = "$id";`

You will get the desired output for `$nextLink`. Hope that helps :)

Comment: There should be no quotes at all.

Comment: Added that too ... maybe he needs to use it later in some other string or something depending on his style of coding.

Comment: Addressing a variable should be without quotes. NO matter how it will be used later.

Comment: It is still valid code. I think the OP gets the point I am trying to make that it is evaluated. Although I have made the edit of it not being advised :)